# RegEx multiple instances

Tags: html, regex, vb.net, parsing

I know that also that is not recommended regex to parse html, but this question is rather to help understand regex than parse html with it.

So I have a sample string (*singleline without any of linebreak or newline*):

```
<tr><th> H1<th>H2 <th> H3 <tr><td> R1C1<td>R1C2 <td> R1C3 <tr><td> R2C1<td>R2C2 <td> R2C3 <tr><td> R3C1<td>R3C2 <td> R3C3 < ..
```

For a better understanding there is 3 row and 3 cells, and the end is unknown tag what but no TR or TD:

```
<tr><th> H1<th>H2 <th> H3 
<tr><td> R1C1<td>R1C2 <td> R1C3 
<tr><td> R2C1<td>R2C2 <td> R2C3 
<tr><td> R3C1<td>R3C2 <td> R3C3 
< ..
```

First try I'd like to get only all of the rows, here is how I think with the expected results:

- start with `<tr>`
- following zero or more any character
- the end starts with `<` what follows zero or more any character but not `td` or `th`

I'm tried with 'basics' to see how it works..

1. With pattern `(<tr>.*?)` why only get `<tr>` strings, and not TR to TR?
2. With pattern `(<tr>.*?<tr)` why only get 1st and 3rd rows only?
3. I don't find any pattern what is good for the end of the string. I've tried with this pattern:

`(<tr>.*?<(?!(td)|(th)))`

..but I'm not sure is this good, moreover this gives back only 1st and 3rd rows.

Here is a [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/2ePBhG/2) what I've tried.

Comment: WHich programming language are you using? There's a solution with lookarounds if they are supported.

Comment: I'm using vb.net

Comment: Use HtmlAgilityPack to parse HTML in VB.NET.

Comment: Yes,I've read about it, but as I mentioned this is about better understanding regex

Comment: Better understanding of regex also includes the understanding when to use it and when to refrain from using it. Perhaps, that is even more important than understanding the regex syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern is:

```
(<tr>.*?(?=<tr))
```

Now the answer to the first 2 questions.

**Question 1**: With pattern `(<tr>.*?)` why only get `<tr>` strings, and not TR to TR?

Because with `*?` you are asking for a lazy operator. Since it is lazy, it tries to match less character as possible. And since 0 characters fulfill the pattern, it stops to 0.

**Question 2**: With pattern `(<tr>.*?<tr)` why only get 1st and 3rd rows only?

Because the parser's cursor is already passed over the 2nd `<tr` while you are getting the first match. In the second match it doesn't go back, because the 2nd `<tr` is part of the first match.

Using lookahead (`(?=<tr)`) the parser does not consume the 2nd `<tr` in the first match. Your last pattern is almost good, but even with that, the `<` of the 2nd TR tag is consumed in the first match, so it can't be part of the second match.

Comment: Thank you the explanations. The pattern you gave is good for the Question 2, but with lookahead how can I solve this: "the end starts with < what follows zero or more any character but not td or th"

Comment: As you did in the question, but using the `<` within the lookahead: `(<tr>.*?)(?=<)(?!<t[dh])` or `(<tr>.*?)(?=<(?!t[dh]))`